# how to declare variables in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, label, sprite

I am learning Swift and noticed there are different ways to declare a variable.

Questions: What is the difference between the following 3 lines, and when to use which?

```
var mySprite: SKSpriteNode?

var mySprite = SKSpriteNode()

var mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: String())
```

Similarly, what is the difference between the following 3 lines and when to use which?

```
var myLabel: SKLabelNode?  

var myLabel = SKLabelNode() 

var myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "name")
```

Comment: These are simply different ways of configuring a variable... You may want to read more about variable initialization and optionals. This is clearly explained in Apple's "The Swift Programming Language"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mySprite: SKSpriteNode?
```

The type of your variable is optional in this case which means it is nil at the time you create an instance of a class containing this variable, which is a property of your class.

```
var mySprite = SKSpriteNode()
```

Here you initialize your property at the time you make an instance of your class which contains it.

```
var mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: String())
```

Similar as number two. But different in the initialization method used. Init().

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in 2 last lines in both cases in terms of declaring a variable.

First declaration differs from last two in that it is declaring an optional value of type `SKLabelNode` with a default value of `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of code will declare the variable as

> Optional

. `Optional` variable in swift means that it could be nil or it could have a value, and you always should safely unwrap it using the "if let" expression.

the second and the third line will define a new object of the class `SKSpriteNode` or `SKLabelNode` but each with different parameters.